# Leaflet GetFeatureInfo

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo

In Leaflet how can I select and query objects inserted through WMS?

Comment: A WMS doesn't insert objects, it gives you map images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

The JSFiddle you linked to shows you exactly how to select objects from WMS.

Here's the documentation for WMS: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo

You can select objects with WMS by parameters too.